# TypeScript: Returning `_.orderBy` from a function, what return type to use?

Tags: string, typescript, types, casting, lodash

The packages I've got installed are `lodash` and `@types/lodash`.

I've got:

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

function doSomething(): string[] {
  const letters = ['c', 'a', 'b'];

  return _.orderBy(letters, [null], ['asc']);
}

console.log(doSomething());
```

But `return _.orderBy(letters, [null], ['asc']);` throws the error:

```
Type '(string | number | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (() => string) | (() => string) | (() => string | undefined) | ((...items: string[]) => number) | ... 25 more ... | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string | number | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (() => string) | (() => string) | (() => string | undefined) | ((...items: string[]) => number) | ... 25 more ... | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Yet clearly, an array of strings will be returned.

Is there any way to fix this, other than force-casting it to `return _.orderBy(letters, [null], ['asc']) as string[];`? Is there a way to specify the type for the `orderBy` be inherited from `letters`?

Comment: What typings are you using? I installed lodash via `npm i --save lodash` and the return type I get for `_.orderBy` is `any`. Yours seems to have a more thoroughly described type...

Comment: Works fine for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pshjsv - used `string[]`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The typings I'm using are from the `@types/lodash` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is because the value `[null]` you are passing to the `iteratees` argument (the second one) does not match the signature of the function.

The `iteratees` argument is [documented](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) to be of type `(Array[]|Function[]|Object[]|string[])`.

To fix your call, just replace the second argument with `[_.identity]`, which is the default value, or alternatively set the second argument to `undefined`, which will also trigger the use of the default value. Check out the [MDN Docs on Default Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Examples).

Comment: Yes thanks! I have an ESLint rule that requires that the second and third args be an array, so `_.identity` was indeed the way to go.